# no implicit conversion from nil to integer - when trying to add anything to array

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to build a fairly complex hash and I am strangely getting the error

```
no implicit conversion from nil to integer
```

when I use the line

```
manufacturer_cols << {:field => 'test'}
```

I use the same line later in the same loop, and it works no problem.

The entire code is

```
manufacturer_cols=[]
manufacturer_fields.each_with_index do |mapped_field, index|


        if mapped_field.base_field_name=='exactSKU'

            #this is where it is breaking, if I comment this out, all is good
            manufacturer_cols << { :base_field=> 'test'}


    else


        #it works fine here!
        manufacturer_cols << { :base_field=>mapped_field.base_field_name }
    end
end
```

------- value of manufacturer_fields --------

[{"base_field":{"base_field_name":"Category","id":1,"name":"Category"}},{"base_field":{"base_field_name":"Description","id":3,"name":"Short_Description"}},{"base_field":{"base_field_name":"exactSKU","id":5,"name":"Item_SKU"}},{"base_field":{"base_field_name":"Markup","id":25,"name":"Retail_Price"}},{"base_field":{"base_field_name":"Family","id":26,"name":"Theme"}}]

Comment: It's preferable to put a bit more effort into simplifying your question, rather than producing a large blob of code. Additionally, `hold_hash` doesn't appear anywhere in the code (did you mean `manufacturer_cols`?), and have you tried doing STDERR.puts manufacturer_cols.inspect to indicate what `manufacturer_cols` is?

Comment: What is `manufacturer_cols`? It's not defined.

Comment: sorry Andrew, originally I wasn't going to put the original code, but then realized just display the hold_hash &lt;&lt bit wouldn't be enough of a hint. On the other side, I often get complaints of not showing enough code, so I guess I'm still trying to find the right balance.

Comment: @pedalpete, just like if you were creating a bug-report, put in only the essential code. The issue is we have to sift through a big body of code to find what is wrong.

Comment: In order to reproduce what you had, we'd need values of `manufacturer_fields` that cause the same error as you observe for the code you have above.

Comment: I understand the downvotes as the question wasn't presented as anything even remotely reproducible, but I've given it an upvote and I will tell you why.  This is actually a rare error and not an easy one to debug.  I've given the best answer I could below...

Comment: @Andrew Grimm, I've added the manufacturer_fields values. Not sure if that is actually going to help.

Comment: Could this be a memory allocation error?? I've got a fairly large csv file which this code is working with (further down the page), and if I comment out the part that goes through the csv, line by line, I don't get this error. The csv is about 2000 lines and 48 columns

Comment: Is the value you've supplied for `manufacturer_fields` meant to be Ruby code, or something else? Possibly JSON?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

#### Implicit Conversion Errors Explained

I'm not sure precisely why your code is getting this error but I can tell you exactly what the error means, and perhaps that will help.

There are two kinds of conversions in Ruby: *explicit* and *implicit.*

Explicit conversions use the short name, like `#to_s` or `#to_i.` These are commonly defined in the core, and they are called all the time. They are for objects that are not strings or not integers, but can be converted for debugging or database translation or string interpolation or whatever.

Implicit conversions use the long name, like `#to_str` or `#to_int.` This kind of conversion is for objects that are very much like strings or integers and merely need to know when to assume the form of their alter egos. These conversions are never or almost never defined in the core.  (Hal Fulton's *The Ruby Way* identifies *Pathname* as one of the classes that finds a reason to define `#to_str`.)

It's quite difficult to get your error, even `NilClass` defines explicit (short name) converters:

```
nil.to_i
=> 0

">>#{nil}<<" # this demonstrates nil.to_s
=> ">><<"
```

You can trigger it like so:

```
Array.new nil
TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer
```

***Therefore,*** your error is coming from the C code inside the Ruby interpreter.  A core class, implemented in C, is being handed a `nil` when it expects an `Integer`. It may have a `#to_i` but it doesn't have a `#to_int` and so the result is the *TypeError.*

Comment: Thanks for your response DigitalRoss, and your comments above. I had done a search as to what the error actually means, but your description is much clearer than anything else I had seen in my searches.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been completely unrelated to anything that had anything to do with manufacturer_cols after all.

I had arrived at the manufacturer_cols bit because if I commented that out, it ran fine.

However, if I commented out the part where I ran through the csv further down the page, it ran fine also.

It turns out the error was related to retrieving attempting to append the base_field when it was nil.

I thought I could use

```
manufacturer_cols.each do |col|
   base_value = row[col[:row_index].to_i]

   if col[:merges]
       col[:merges].each do |merge|
           base_value += merge[:separator].to_s + row[merge[:merge_row_index]]
       end
   end
end
```

unfortunately, that caused the error. the solution was

```
 base_value = base_value + merge[:separator].to_s + row[merge[:merge_row_index]]
```

I hope this helps somebody, 'cause as DigitalRoss alluded to, it was quite a wild goose chase nailing down where in the code this was being caused and why.

Comment: So you started off with `base_value`, but then had `bsae_value`?

Comment: sorry, clearly that was a typing error. I paired down the code only showing the relevant bits, and probably deleted too much and just typed it in.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when parsing through an API for "tag/#{idnum}/parents"...Normally, you'd expect a response like this:

```
 {

"parents": [
    {
        "id": 8,
        "tag_type": "MarketTag",
        "name": "internet",
        "display_name": "Internet",
        "angellist_url": "https://angel.co/internet",
        "statistics": {
            "all": {
                "investor_followers": 1400,
                "followers": 5078,
                "startups": 13214
            },
            "direct": {
                "investor_followers": 532,
                "followers": 1832,
                "startups": 495
            }
        }
    }
],
"total": 1,
"per_page": 50,
"page": 1,
"last_page": 1
```

}

but when I looked up the parents of the market category "adult" (as it were), I got this

```
{

"parents": [ ],
"total": 0,
"per_page": 50,
"page": 1,
"last_page": 0

}
```

Now ruby allowed a number of interactions with this thing to occur, but eventually it threw the error about implicit conversion

```
    parents.each do |p|
        stats = p['statistics']['all']
        selector << stats['investor_followers'].to_i
    end
    selected = selector.index(selector.max)
    parents[selected]['id'] ***<--- CODE FAILED HERE
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple fix for me.

When I was getting this error using the Scout app, one of my mapped folders was header-1, when I removed the hyphen from the folder name and made it header1, the error went away.

It didn't like the hyphen for some reason...