# Number in array not typed as integer?

Tags: ruby, types

Given the following:

```
def test(arr)
  cache = []
  for i in 0..arr.length
    if !cache[arr[i]] # no implicit conversion from nil to integer
      cache[arr[i]] = true
    end
    if !cache[arr[i]].to_i # no implicit conversion from nil to integer
      cache[arr[i]] = true
    end
    if !cache[arr[i].to_i] # works fine
      cache[arr[i]] = true
    end
  end
end

puts test([1, 5, 8, 11])
```

Why does `cache[arr[i]]` require the `to_i` conversion? From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6120326/4769440)

> your error is coming from the C code inside the Ruby interpreter. A core class, implemented in C, is being handed a nil when it expects an Integer. It may have a #to_i but it doesn't have a #to_int and so the result is the TypeError.

I don't see how converting `arr[i].to_i` solves the error, since `arr[i]` is already an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting into trouble here primarily because you're using `for`, and you're using it incorrectly. As odd as it might seem, `for` is hardly ever used in Ruby. Instead `each` and other Enumerable variants are encouraged.

Here's a more Ruby idiomatic version of your code:

```
def test(arr)
  cache = [ ]

  arr.each_with_index do |e, i|
    cache[i] = true
  end

  cache
end
```

You can even refactor this further if you're doing a simple transform where the index isn't relevant:

```
def test(arr)
  arr.map do |e|
    true
  end
end
```

If you inspected what value `i` was assuming during each iteration of your loop you'd see it creeps past the end of your array, and so ends up returning `nil` from an out-of-bounds call. `.to_i` converts this back to `0` which paves over the problem but doesn't fix it.

If you want to use ranges like that use `0...arr.length` where the `...` operator goes up to *but does not include* the ending bound.

Comment: I can't agree with the first sentence. The issue has nothing to do with `for` or its incorrect usage, it's a simple off-by-one error. There's nothing *wrong* with using `for`, or the way he's using `for`, it just happens to be discourage in favor of `.each` *by convention*. He would have encountered the same problem if he used `(0..arr.length).each do |i|` instead of using `for`.

Comment: @meagar What I mean is using `for` in the classic sense *invites* off-by-one errors. I don't know how many bits of C or C++ code I've seen with issues precisely like this. `each` is almost foolproof, it only iterates over what's present in the array, and `each_with_index` is likewise safe.

Comment: `for` can also be foolproof, and it absolutely does not invite off-by-one errors when used correctly, the same as `.each`. If he'd used `for i in arr` things would have been fine. I agree completely that `.each` is by far the more idiomatic way of iterating over an enumerable, but I still disagree with blaming `for` for the problems here.

Comment: I marked this as the answer since I appreciate the more idiomatic examples. I also agree that `each` seems less prone to error.

Comment: @Daniel_L The real power of Ruby is in the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html) module as there's a method for nearly every occasion in there. It's worth having a look through there to see what's available as some of those methods can save you a ton of time. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be due to that fact that you iteration goes one past the end of your input array.

0..arr.length will process indexes of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 for your test example. The last element of that array has an index of 3.

I believe you want 0...arr.length to make this make more sense.

Note the ... in the second example vs .. in yours.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing an element that doesn't exist: the first index is 0, the last index is `length-1`, ergo `arr[arr.length]` doesn't exist and returns `nil`, which means that `cache[arr[arr.length]]` is `cache[nil]`, and since `cache` is an array and arrays are indexed by integers, it tries to convert `nil` to an integer using `to_int` but fails.

The immediate fix is to not iterate till `arr.length`, either by constructing the inclusive range till `arr.length-1` or using an exclusive range.

But the *real* answer is that anytime you are writing a loop, you are doing something wrong and there is a method in the `Enumerable` API that you should rather be using instead. Unfortunately, it is not quite clear from your code what it is even supposed to be doing, right now it simply returns the range and has no side-effects, so it is pretty much doing nothing.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def test(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |el, acc| acc[el] = true end
end

test([1, 5, 8, 11])
#=> [nil, true, nil, nil, nil, true, nil, nil, true, nil, nil, true]
```

Comment: This is a more accurate implementation of the OP code, than the actual accepted answer